# Make function to read Temperature from DS18B20 and show on LCD

Tags: c, embedded, beagleboneblack

I want to create a new function that will return me a actual temperature from DS18B20 as a float variable. I need that kind of variable to place a string on LCD.

Already I'm using function to read temperature like that:

```
int8_t readTemp(struct ds18b20 *d) {
struct ds18b20 *newTemp;
char tempAct[5];
while (d->next != NULL)
{
    d = d->next;
    int fd = open(d->devPath, O_RDONLY);

    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("Couldn't open the w1 device.");
        return 1;
    }
    char buf[256];
    ssize_t numRead;
    while ((numRead = read(fd, buf, 256)) > 0)
    {
        newTemp = malloc(sizeof(struct ds18b20));
        strncpy(newTemp->tempData, strstr(buf, "t=") + 2, 5);
        //float tempC = strtof(d->tempData, NULL);
        sprintf(tempAct, "%s C", newTemp->tempData);
        //printf("Device: %s  - ", d->devID);
        //printf("Temp: %.3f C  ", tempC / 1000);
        //printf("%.3f F\n\n", (tempC / 1000) * 9 / 5 + 32);
    }
    close(fd);
}
return 1;}
```

I have problem with sprintf from this line:

```
  sprintf(tempAct, "%s C", newTemp->tempData);
```

In the main code:

```
int main(void) {
struct ds18b20 *rootNode;
struct ds18b20 *devNode;
struct ds18b20 *getTemp;
// Load pin configuration. Ignore error if already loaded
system("echo w1 > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.9/slots>/dev/null");
while (1) {
    rootNode = malloc(sizeof(struct ds18b20));
    devNode = rootNode;
    getTemp = rootNode;
    int8_t devCnt = findDevices(devNode);
    printf("\n Found %d devices\n\n", devCnt);
    int8_t tempAct = readTemp(getTemp);
    printf("\n Temp Act: %d \n\n", tempAct);
    //readTemp(rootNode);
    // Free linked list memory

    while (rootNode) {

        // Start with current value of root node
        devNode = rootNode;
        // Save address of next devNode to rootNode before deleting current devNode
        rootNode = devNode->next;
        // Free current devNode.
        free(devNode);
    }
    free(rootNode);
}
return 0;}
```

I'm trying to recreate the functions from finddevices:

```
int8_t devCnt = findDevices(devNode);
    printf("\n Found %d devices\n\n", devCnt);
    int8_t tempAct = readTemp(getTemp);
    printf("\n Temp Act: %d \n\n", tempAct);
```

But the tempData* isn't imported from readTemp fuction to main code.

Comment: ....and that ds18b20 struct looks like......?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is littered with issues that are not explicitly part of your question.  Just some:

- `readTemp()` does not return temperature.  In fact it returns 1 if it fails and 1 if it succeeds.  That is probably an error.
- `readTemp()` appears to read *all* available temperature sensors, passed to it as a linked list of `struct ds18b20` not just one.  But actually skips the root node and accesses the second and subsequent without checking it is valid.  If the root node contains no device (just a pointer to the first device), then you need only pass it pass `rootNode->next` instead.
- It is not clear why it dynamically allocates a new `struct ds18b20` or why it fails to later de-allocate.  That is a serious memory leak.

At a guess the following is more likely to be close to what you need (without knowing anything about `struct ds18b20` or what the expected output of the sensor is - just going by the evidence in the code (and commented out code) you have posted - so some bold assumptions have been made.

```
int readTemp( struct ds18b20 *d,         // List of sensors
              float* temperatures,       // Pointer to array to receive temperatures
              int8_t max_temperatures )  // Max number of temperatures to receive
{
    struct ds18b20* sensor = d ;
    int count = 0 ;
    while( sensor != NULL && count < max_temperatures )
    {
        int fd = open( sensor->devPath, O_RDONLY ) ;
        if( fd >= 0 )
        {
            if( read( fd, buf, sizeof(buf) ) > 0 )
            {
                char buf[256];
                char* temp_str = strstr(buf, "t=") + 2 ;
                sscanf( temp_str, "%f", &temperatures[count] ) ;
                temperatures[count] /= 1000 ;
                count++ ;
            }
            close( fd ) ;

            sensor = sensor->next ;
        }
        else
        {
            perror("Couldn't open the w1 device.");
        }
    }

    return count ;
}
```

Then in you can call it thus:

```
int8_t devCount = findDevices( rootNode ) ;

float* temperatures = malloc( devCnt * sizeof(float) ) ;
int8_t tempCount = readTemp( rootNode->next, temperatures, devCount ) ;

for( int i = 0; i < tempCount; i++ )
{
    printf( "Temp Act: %f\n", temperatures[i] ) ;
}

free( temperatures ) ;
```

If you know there is only one device or you only need print the first, then this can be simplified:

```
int8_t devCount = findDevices( rootNode ) ;
if( devCount > 0 )
{
    float temperature = 0f ;
    int8_t tempCount = readTemp( rootNode->next, temperature, 1 ) ;
    if( tempCount > 0 )
    {
        printf( "Temp Act: %f\n", temperature ) ;
    }
}
```

Issues in your `main()` are also varied, including:

- The root node is needlessly dynamically allocated
- several aliases to the root node are needlessly created
- The device list is repeatedly re-enumerated and the device list allocated and free'd on every iteration of a non-terminating loop.  Assuming the number of sensors does not change while the code is running, this is unnecessary.
- The loop never ends - even in the event of an error.

A better implementation might look something like:

```
int main(void) 
{
    // Load pin configuration. Ignore error if already loaded
    system("echo w1 > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.9/slots>/dev/null");

    struct ds18b20 rootNode = { 0 } ;
    int8_t devCount = findDevices( rootNode ) ;

    if( devCount > 0)
    {
        struct ds18b20* devlist = rootNode->next ;
        float* temperatures = malloc( devCount * sizeof(float) ) ;
        int8_t tempCount = 0 ;

        do
        {
            tempCount = readTemp( devList, temperatures, devCount ) ;

            for( int i = 0; i < tempCount; i++ )
            {
                printf( "Temp Act: %f\n", temperatures[i] ) ;
            }

        } while (tempCount > 0 ) ;

        // Free resources after a temperature read fails 
        free( temperatures ) ;

        // Free linked list memory
        while( devlist != NULL ) 
        {
            // Save address of next before deleting current
            struct ds18b20* next = devlist->next ;

            // Free current devNode.
            free( devlist ) ;

            // get next
            devlist = next ;
        }
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: I dont this like that: 

Maybe this will help someone with that problem couse i solved this.

The original loop looked like that:

   if(dirent->d_type == DT_LNK && strstr(dirent->d_name, "28-") != NULL)

I changed it to:

 if(dirent->d_type == 4)
        {
          if (strstr(dirent->d_name, "28-") != NULL)
          {

After that everything is working perfectly.